# App record with bundle identifier "xxx" not found on App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, validation

**App record with bundle identifier "com.lovesongforever.croquetpaddleIOS" not found on App Store Connect**

Here is a completely descriptive set of screenshots that tell the whole story:

[Certificates and Identifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeGdQ.png)

Monster Paddle iOS Game + Monster Paddle tvOS Game did *validate*

Croquet Paddle iOS Game + Croquet Paddle tvOS Game did *not*

As shown in these last two screenshots, these errors claim that the respective Bundle ID was not found on App Store Connect ... yet, the top-most above screenshot shows that is **not** true.

[iOS validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEoVJ.png)

[tvOS validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2sgS.png)

Comment: What do you use this bundle id for? You created on the developer page, so it's unique for sure.

Comment: You are showing that id in the developer portal, but have you created an app entry in App Store Connect?  That is what it says - it can find the app in App Store Connect.

Answer (score -2):

Based on [Paulw11's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77371452/app-record-with-bundle-identifier-xxx-not-found-on-app-store-connect#comment136401381_77371452):

[Submission = SUCCESSFUL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RjCr.png)

Way back when I uploaded my first app, I **now** remember that after I selected "Archive", I waited for that to finish. I then selected Validate, and if successful, I found my preliminary app on "App Connect" where I added screenshots and words as required within the latter's web site. So after validation, I then do all the other work, including submission to the App Store within App Connect, not Xcode.